# VirtualBox: How to access host network card from guest

Tags: wireshark, kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu as guest on a Win7 host. In Kubuntu I have installed Wireshark. I want monitor the network card of the Windows host from Kubuntu guest.
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

**Is this possible ?**

Yes :)

You just need to:

1. Set the guest network card to bridged mode ("Attached to: Bridged adapter" in the network settings of the VM) in virtualbox manager on the host.
2. Once the adapter is bridged, you then click on "Advanced" on the same settings screen. This will reveal extra settings including promiscuous mode. Change to "Allow All". This configures virtualbox to allow the guest adapter to be set to promiscuous mode.

Sometimes the promiscuous mode setting doesn't work, You can force it using the command line. See `--nicpromisc` setting for the bridged guest card to `allow-all` in the following link: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm

Once these two steps are done, then start the KUbuntu guest, load Wireshark, tell Wireshark to use promiscuous mode and sniff the traffic.